# Referencing and evaluating another cell's array formula to create master array using VSTACK, in Excel without VBA/Macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm trying to accomplish this task in Excel without VBA, Macros, or Power Query.

Here is a workbook with example sheets of data, an intermediate sheet, and a sheet showing the desired outcome: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiN1s6QeAJ28nCoh1gYWmXAXaw2L?e=Xr3JoP

The crux of the issue is getting from the intermediate sheet to the desired outcome. I want to stack arrays of varying lengths into one master array. However, I can't get a final `VSTACK()` code working that references the evaluated output of another cell. Instead, I'm only able to get the final `VSTACK()` working if I manually enter each individual array formula into the code. Obviously, I don't want to do this.

Here is working code that produces an array of 13 columns and a variable number of rows pulling data from other sheets in the workbook. `IFERROR` evaluates to blank if there is no matching sheet name or if the number of entries on that sheet are 0. `HSTACK` retrieves the sheet name and appends a column  with that sheet name to the other array in the `HSTACK` formula. The second array in the `HSTACK` uses `INDIRECT` to find a sheet name listed in column A:A and returns columns B:M from that sheet with a variable number of rows based on the highest number found in column B:B.

`=IFERROR(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!$B$4")&"|",IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!B:B")),"")),"|",,TRUE)),INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!$B$13:M"&SUM(IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!B:B")),""),12))),"")`

My issue is taking this equation and combining multiple entries into a final `VSTACK` formula. If the above code is entered in column D:D, I'd like to do a final `VSTACK` similar to this:

`=VSTACK('Sheetname'!D:D)` or even `=VSTACK(D2:D56)`

However, when I try to reference the cells containing the intermediate code, all I get is what is shown in Column D:D, which includes a lot of `#SPILL!` and doesn't include the other columns of each array. I've tried various forms of `FORMULATEXT` and `INDIRECT` with no luck. So far the only successful formula I've found that accomplishes my end goal is the following, but this example only combines 2 arrays, not the hundreds that I'll need to combine.

`=VSTACK(IFERROR(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!$B$4")&"|",IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!B:B")),"")),"|",,TRUE)),INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!$B$13:M"&SUM(IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A2&"'!B:B")),""),12))),""), IFERROR(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A3&"'!$B$4")&"|",IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A3&"'!B:B")),"")),"|",,TRUE)),INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A3&"'!$B$13:M"&SUM(IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&'Example intermediate sheet'!$A3&"'!B:B")),""),12))),""))`

Comment: the `#SPILL!` error is caused by "something" being in the area being spilled into (in your case the other formulas), notice how the last formula "works": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to create formula that will stack hundreds of arrays. The formula would be too long. This is something for VBA. You might be able to do something with powerQuery.

Comment: It almost looks like you are trying to recreate a database from individual "reports". Seems backwards to me...Perhaps you need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish and what alternatives you have.

Comment: Since you said no VBA/Power Query, the only way to shorten your formula is to use recursion with the `LAMBDA` formula.

Comment: Maybe, if your intermediate table contained the parameters of the various data tabs, then you could build a formula using that (as opposed to building the actual formula).

Comment: @gns100 I'm aware of the reason for the #SPILL! error. My general question is, how can I access the stored results of that formula? If it knows it doesn't have enough space to print the results, that means it has calculated the results in some portion of its memory. I want to access those results without having it print them first.